# In terminal, take value of numbers into account when using ls

Tags: bash, terminal, ordering

When listing directories in Bash, I would like the value of numbers to be taken into account.

Currently this is the output I get:

```
$ ls 
test_1.txt  
test_11.txt 
test_12.txt 
test_2.txt  
test_3.txt
```

As you can see, `ls` does not take the value of 11 and 12 into acount and lists it before 2, even though they are bigger numbers.
Is there some way to get the output to be this instead:

```
$ ls 
test_1.txt  
test_2.txt  
test_3.txt
test_11.txt 
test_12.txt
```

I've checked the man page and found nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In GNU coreutils `ls`, the **`ls -v`** (version sort) option should do it.

Otherwise you have to pipe the output through **`sort -n`** or `sort -V`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It seems that [ls -v](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Details-about-version-sort.html#Details-about-version-sort) is only un the GNU coreutils, since man pages for the BSDs give nothing like it. I'm on OSX.

Comment: @termCap You can install `coreutils` later using [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation)